# Solution to a Particular Equation

Tags: real-analysis

I have come across an equation of the following form
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^{2}}[C_{1}x+C_{2}y+C_{3}x^{2}y + C_{3}y^{2}x] = C_{4}xy$$
where $C_{j}$ are real-valued constants. I'd like to be able to solve for $x$ in closed form, in terms of $y$ and the $C_{j}$. Alternately, I would also like to show the following result (which I am not sure holds): given $C_{1}<C_{2}$, show that for any $x,y$ satisfying this equation, $x>y$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I mean the constants to be arbitrary except for the one restriction mentioned, so I am looking for a general solution in that sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $C_1=C_3=0$ and $C_2=1$ (so $C_1\lt C_2$), the equation simplifies to $${\rm stuff\ }=C_4x$$ so $x$ can be pretty much anything just by choosing $C_4$ appropriately. In particular, $x\le y$ is not ruled out.

Comment: stuff is what? please explain.

Comment: I mean the constants to be arbitrary with no restrictions except what I mentioned. So although this is true for a particular case I hope to solve in general.

Comment: If $x\gt y$ is false in a particular case, then you're not going to be able to show that it's true in general, are you?

Comment: Anyway, you're not going to be able to solve that equation for $x$ in closed form. It's not even possible to solve $xe^x=2$ in closed form in terms of exponentials, logs, trig functions, powers, square roots, etc.